# Run Sonar from another machine

Tags: maven, configuration, sonarqube

I've setup on my machine(1) SonarQube with Maven/Jacoco/Surefire plugins,
but I want to test a project that belongs to another machine(2) and get the results
on the server of the #1 machine. Both have SonarQube already setup.

So, I tried to set as a host url the address of the #1 machine and its db:

Settings for the **#2** machine:

**settings.xml:**

```
<sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://<#1_machine_address>:3306/sonar</sonar.jdbc.url
<sonar.jdbc.driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</sonar.jdbc.driverClassName
<sonar.jdbc.username>sonar</sonar.jdbc.username> <sonar.jdbc.password>sonar</sonar.jdbc.password>
<sonar.host.url>http://<#1_machine_address>:9000</sonar.host.url>
```

**sonar/conf/sonar.properties:**

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://<#1_machine_address>:3306/sonar
```

Settings on **#1** machine:

**settings.xml:**

```
<sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar</sonar.jdbc.url>
<sonar.jdbc.username>sonar</sonar.jdbc.username>
<sonar.jdbc.password>sonar</sonar.jdbc.password>
<sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>
```

**sonar.properties:**

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

>

I run 
`mvn sonar:sonar` 
from the #2 machine, but I get an error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.2:sonar (default-cli) on
>   project openbet-shared_tcl-util: Can not execute SonarQube analysis:
>   **Fail to connect to database: Cannot load JDBC driver class
>   'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'** -> [Help 1]

**EDIT:**
Above error message comes when Sonar runs only on the #1machine.
When it runs on both machines, I get this:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.2:sonar (default-cli) on
>   project openbet-shared_tcl-util: Can not execute SonarQube analysis:
>   Fail to connect to database: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory
>   (Communications link failure [ERROR]  [ERROR] The last packet sent
>   successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not
>   received any packets from the server.): Connection refused [ERROR] ->
>   [Help 1]

Comment: It is useless to have a SonarQube server on Machine #2. Could you please remove it? Moreover two different SonarQube servers cannot point to the same database.

Comment: Is it possible to run mvn sonar:sonar when there is no sonar server? If they cannot point to the same db, as you say, what could I do as an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No `sudo` on server with MySQL

Create ssh tunnel for mysql

```
ssh user@1_machine_address -L 9999:localhost:3306 -N
```

Check this configuration with `telnet localhost 9999`.

Configure local sonar and maven to connect to `localhost:9999`.

**settings.xml**

```
<sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:9999/sonar</sonar.jdbc.url>
...
<sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>
```

**sonar.properties**

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:9999/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

### Connection to MySQL refused

Maven sonar plugin cant connect to your database, please make sure that port 3306 is open and accessible. You can check this with command

```
telnet 1_machine_address 3306
```

Check firewall on `1_machine_address`, something like this is needed:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Make sure mysql is configured to be accessible from other servers. By default is not.

Mysql configuration in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` should has defined IP address accessible from remote servers or 0.0.0.0, for example:

```
bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
```

**Caution:** This is potentially dangerous, make sure you are safe with this!

### Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'

Are you sure mysql driver is inplace?

```
sonar/extensions/jdbc-driver/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar
```

and sonar is restarted?

Comment: I don't get what's wrong with the mysql db setup. That's why I posted.Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, mysql driver exists on both machines!

Comment: sonar is restarted? just asking :)

Comment: Both are linux, sonar is restarted and mysql exists. "telnet" for 9000 port connects successfully

Comment: Maven need to connect to both ports: 3306 and 9000, error message is about 3306 (mysql port)

Comment: It refuses connection for 3306 port :/ But Sonar runs for #1 machine (the one that actually uses 3306 port)

Comment: are you using fedora or ubuntu? open this port on firewall (iptables)

Comment: Ubuntu. But I cannot sudo :/

Comment: Tunnel mysql connection with SSH.

Comment: I have some probs :/ 
1) with ssh I get: bind: Address already in use.
2) telnet localhost 9999
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
3) same for telnet <machine> 3306
4) iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
 Permission denied (you must be root)
5) I cannot edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Comment: My error, use this command `ssh user@1_machine_address -L 9999:localhost:3306 -N`. Forget about iptables and my.cnf - this is not needed with SSH Tunnel.

Comment: telnet localhost 9999
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
[
5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1I$Ucp)yJ�N?0ssh1WD0b~mysql_native_passwordConnection closed by foreign host.

AND telnet 1_machine_address 3306: Connection refused :/

Comment: if I try "ssh -f 1_machine_addr -L 9999:localjost:3306 -N":  
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 9999
Could not request local forwarding.

Comment: The error msg now is: Can not execute SonarQube analysis: Fail to connect to database: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.): Connection refused
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]

Comment: Stop, this works: `telnet localhost 9999 Connected to localhost`. This mean your **tunnel is working**, configure sonar and restart. With tunnel sonar is connecting to localhost and packets are transmitted to 1_machine_addres by ssh.

Comment: I've restarted several times. I still get the last error msg that I sent. Sonar server runs on machine1 successfully, as you also commented it connects correctly to tunnel for the db but machine2 fails to connect there :/ Exacty the msg says: "(Communications link failure  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)"

Comment: OK, are you sure that command `telnet localhost 9999` on machine2 still prints `Connected to localhost`?

Comment: Yes, It connects on both machines actually but after a few seconds: >Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: Command `telnet localhost 9999` should failed on machine1, is this true? Port numbers are important. *Connection closed by foreign host* is ok, we are testing only.

Comment: telnet localhost 9999
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
[
5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1WHL&t9]I�j9{"4!Dt;i}Zmysql_native_password

It connects on machine1! :/

Comment: Wrong, execute `ssh user@1_machine_address -L 9999:localhost:3306 -N` from machine2 only (or check with telnet if it is working already)! We need to tunnel from machine2 to machine1. After this sonar on machine2 can connect to *virtual* database `localhost:9999` which is tunneled to machine1.

Comment: bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 9999.

Comment: Probably tunnel is working - check this with telnet `telnet localhost 9999`. How configured is sonar on machine2? Sonar and maven should has configured database as `localhost:9999`, is this true?

Comment: That's it! :| Thank you very much MariuszS! It was running with the address of machine1 and not with localhost!! If you want you can edit your post to mark it as the correct answer! Thanks again!

Comment: Just in case that someone else copies with this issue in the future: It happens that sometimes I have to "reopen" the ssh tunnel. But simple ssh doesnt work. Try instead:
 "ssh -f host_addr -L 9999:localhost:3306 -N"